# Native JS Binary Render

Tags: javascript, image, google-chrome-extension, filereader

So I need to make a way to import a file and show it on the user's screen. I cannot use PHP, as it is for a chrome extension. I am using the `fileReader()` API, and am using this to read the binary file. Is there any way to render an image directly from the user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Skip the FileReader part.  Take the File or Blob you're reading and create an object URL for it.

```
img.src = URL.createObjectURL(file);
```

Comment: I need to get it from the user's computer.

Comment: @bluninja1234 Yes, you can still do that.  The URL this creates is not a server-side URL, but a `blob:` URL that references the local file data.  Use the same file object here as you would have if you were using the FileReader.

Comment: Then what is `file` in this case?

Comment: @bluninja1234 A file instance.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File  If you'd show your code that you had with FileReader, I can give you an in-context example.  Again, whatever file reference you passed to FileReader, you can use that reference here.

Comment: @bluninja1234 please note that you need to [manually release its memory](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL#Memory_management) if your extension is memory intensive.

Comment: @YongQuan This isn't different than anything else really.  The object URL resource will be released when the page context is unloaded.  This is automatic.  If your context is long-lived (such as in this case with a browser extension), yes, you should release anything you're no longer using.  Just like you would have to do if you injected a ton of crap into the DOM, like your answer suggests.

Comment: It's a new tab extension built on native JS for fast load times, so I suppose that I don't need to release with `URL.revokeObjectURL`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`FileReader.readAsDataURL()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsDataURL) for images.

Simply read the documentation.

Try it yourself:

```js
const input = document.getElementById('input');
const img = document.getElementById('img');

const reader = new FileReader();

reader.addEventListener('load', showImage);
input.addEventListener('change', readImage);

function readImage(){
  if (!this.files) return;
  reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
}

function showImage(){
  img.src = this.result;
}
```

```html
<input id="input" type="file" onchange="showImage()">
<img id="img">
```

Read more about [FileReader API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader).

**EDIT - for future readers**

It's unfair to judge `FileReader.readAsDataURL()` by only one argument, that it is "horribly inefficient". After all, if it is in the standard spec, it serves its own purpose.

While `FileReader.readAsDataURL()` is indeed less efficient than `URL.createObjectURL()` in this case, there is a difference:

1. `.readAsDataURL` is asynchronous, `.createObjectURL()` is not.
2. `.readAsDataURL` can be garbage collected automatically, [`.createObjectURL` cannot](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL#Memory_management).

But of course, these difference can be trivial, depending on your apps' implementation and application.

Comment: This is horribly inefficient.  It requires reading the entire object, base64-encoding, and shoving it into the DOM.

Comment: *".readAsDataURL is asynchronous, .createObjectURL() is not."* 
 It doesn't have to be asynchronous because it returns a blob URL to you instantly.  No real work is done!  In your case, you're reading and encoding the entire resource!  This is a massive overhead, so the function needs to be async.  What a ridiculous argument you're making.  *".readAsDataURL can be garbage collected automatically"*  You still have to remove it from the DOM as well as clean up any references!